# How to increase the timeout limit of nvidia-docker initialization

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I would like to know how to increase the timeout limit of nvidia-docker at  initialization.

When 2 or more of my 4-GPU server are busy, I always get a timeout error:

> nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: timed out

when launching docker:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to the question, but only a workaround to overcome the timed out error.

Before launching docker, run `nvidia-smi` to see which processes are running on GPUs. Disable these processes using:

```
kill -TSTP [pid]
```

Then launch docker. When done continue the previously disabled processes using:

```
kill -CONT [pid]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change the timeout, though you can work around this problem by starting `nvidia-persistenced` beforehand, which will initialize the GPU devices and keep them open, so the driver doesn't have to go through that process during docker startup.